# Simulating Correlation (but sample correlation is always too low)

Tags: monte-carlo, correlation, simulations

I am trying to **simulate correlation** in order to price a correlation swap (via Monte-Carlo). For simplicity, let's assume we have 2 assets, and everything is correlated with $\rho$, and there is no drift or anything. Say, the swap has $M$ observation periods, and we simulate $N$ paths per asset.

So we start by using a **multivariate normal distribution** with $\mu=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}1&\rho\\\rho&1\end{bmatrix}$. Now we generate $M$ correlated pairs of normal variables $R = \begin{bmatrix}r_{11}&\ldots & r_{1M}\\r_{21}&\ldots&r_{2M}\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times M}$. We do this $N$ times, such that we obtain $R_1,\ldots,R_N$. For each sample $R_i$ we now compute the **realised sample correlation** $\bar{\rho}_i$ between its 2 assets.

Finally, we can compute the average of all realised sample correlations:
$$\bar{\rho} = \frac1N \cdot\sum_{i=1}^N \bar{\rho}_i$$

What I have noticed is, the average realised sample correlation is **disproportionally often** lower than the *target correlation*, i.e.
$$\bar{\rho} < \rho$$
I would have expected $\bar{\rho} \approx \rho$.

Below are a few sample plots, which highlight this effect (with 3 out of 4 paths lower than 50%, and 1 path around 50%):

[image]
Source Code to generate graph: [zerobin](https://zerobin.net/?a648d1fbd924693e#Cq9Wae6jSGwSHCSUPZD9FQCh0UyODsrQyEm3yuUk2Pw=)

---

**Question: Does anybody know why this is the case? Or am I generating random variables incorrectly?**

Answer (score 1):

[Sample correlation is known to be a biased estimator.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/220961/247274)

Biased estimators are perfectly acceptable, and many common estimators are biased, such as:

1. [Sample standard deviation $s$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11707/247274)
2. [Logistic regression maximum likelihood estimators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/94322/247274)

Comment: In your code example, you use N=50. Increase to a higher number (say 500, 5000) to see that the estimator will converge.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I did not give any code. Which example do you mean? // Consistent estimators can be biased. Unbiased estimators have their expectation equal to the true value no matter the sample size.

Comment: my comment was meant to second your answer, it was directed at the OP. Sorry for not making that clear enough.